# module is not defined, exports is not defined - with typescript + react

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, typescript

I have a very simple app using ASP 4/MVC 5, and Typescript (2.3.1.0)

Here's the basic layout:

tsconfig.json

```
{

  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "Scripts/**/*.ts",
    "Scripts/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

app.tsx (compiled to app.js using typescript tools for visual studio)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface FooProps {
    name: string;
}

export default class Hello extends React.Component<FooProps, undefined> {
    render() {
        return <h1>Hello from {this.props.name} !</h1>
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/node_modules/react/react.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I run, this appears in the console:
[image]

I'm trying to do this without using something like browserify/webpack. My question is, is it possible... and if so, how?

**Edit**

app.jsx looks like this after the tsx -> jsx transpilation:

```
"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var react_1 = require("react");
var Hello = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Hello, _super);
    function Hello() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    Hello.prototype.render = function () {
        return <h1>Hello from {this.props.name} !</h1>;
    };
    return Hello;
}(react_1.default.Component));
//# sourceMappingURL=app.jsx.map
```

Note, the error is thrown here:

`Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });`

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Comment: how does the `app.js` look after transpiling..?

Comment: @Searching Added an edit with the transpiled jsx.

Comment: You need SystemJS, or Webpack to dynamically parse these ES Module syntax. A few browsers currently support it, but not enough to make a full app work.

Comment: I was assuming that the babel transpilation taking place in the [`BabelBundle` here](https://reactjs.net/) would have handled that.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm trying to do this without using something like browserify/webpack" -- the short answer is no.  ES2015 import/export syntax is not currently supported by any browsers.  So I'm not sure how you expect it to work in a browser without some kind of transcompilation step.  The most popular way to do that is with Webpack/Babel, but you could use just Babel....

If you really want to avoid any transcompilation, you'll have to avoid future language features.  So `React` and `ReactDOM` would have to be in the global namespace, and all your components would either have to be in the same file, or loaded into the global namespace.  I feel like this would be an uphill battle, but it's certainly doable.

Comment: I am using the API documented at https://reactjs.net/ for transpiling and bundling my jsx. It's a [BabelBundle](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/tree/master/src/System.Web.Optimization.React). I'd assume this would do what it needs to do to generate runnable ES5 javascript?